# Tabulator not downloading using Tabulator.download

Tags: download, tabulator

Tabulator not downloading using Tabulator.download(). I have tried using CSV as well as xlsx format however no success. I am using the npm package in a react component. The data is visible in the table on UI.

It fails at the following function:

```
Download.prototype.downloaders = {
    csv: function csv(columns, data, options, setFileContents, config)
```

The stack trace shown in the console is:

```
 Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
  at parseRows (tabulator.js:11677)
  at Download.csv (tabulator.js:11722)
  at Download.download (tabulator.js:11419)
  at Tabulator.download (tabulator.js:8337)
```

Comment: please post the code for the download function you are calling

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is an issue specific to the react version of tabulator. Found a solution here:

https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/issues/76

Just add this to your options object:

```
options  = {
    downloadDataFormatter: (data) => data,
    downloadReady: (fileContents, blob) => blob,
}
```

Comment: You can also define this as an attribute on the React component as well    <ReactTabulator
                    ref={ref => (ref = ref)}
                    columns={columns}
                    data={data}
                    options={options}
                    downloadDataFormatter={data => data}
                    downloadReady={(fileContents, blob) => blob}
                    rowClick={this.handleRowClick}
                />